# Python: Intelligent eval of conditions

Tags: python, conditional-statements, eval

I have conditions within strings (in python condition notation), e.g. like so:

```
my_str = "0 and (not (1 and 0) or B_undefined_variable)"
```

I want to compute the condition result (In a mathematical sense). I'm using `eval` (No worries I know it is evil ;-)).

```
my_result = eval(my_str)
```

I found out, it even works when B is used as a letter without being defined as a variable, because `0 and ANYTHING` is always False.

Now when I do it the other way round:

```
eval("Some_Undefined_Var and 0")
```

it stops working. So eval seems to raise a NameError-Exception without *TRYING* to finish parsing the whole equation.

Do you know of ANY module / library in Python which does try to solve such conditions?

Thanks!

---

Thanks for your answers. 
It seems I didn't explain it very well. 
I don't want to return False in case of a NameError - I want the condition to be evaluated if it COULD be evaluated. And indeed, it could, no matter whether the variable is defined or not.

It should be computed in a mathematical sense, i.e. `0 *and* ANYTHING` will ALWAYS be False. The same applies for `1 *OR* ANYTHING` --> Will ALWAYS yield TRUE, no matter what..

And I'd like to make it work for reverted conditions as well. You, as a human would also say, that `NO_MATTER_WHAT && 0` gives 0. Even though the parser would immediately quit after seeing `NO_MATTER_WHAT` is not defined...

Comment: The LHS of the expression is evaluated first due to SCE. So it will return `NameError`

Comment: I think that is how compilers.. interpreters supposed to work.. i.e raise a NameError-Exception without TRYING to finish parsing

Comment: How about modifying the string such that the code in the string checks whether the variable exists before trying to evaluate the variable, e.g., `eval("('foo' in locals() or 'foo' in globals()) and foo and 0")`?

Comment: What would the solution be? If you want the result of an expression with an undefined value to be False, just catch the exception and return False.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. It seems I didnt explain it very well. I don't want to return False in case of a NameError - I want the conition to be evaluated if it COULD be evaluated. And indeed, it could, no matter whether the variable is defined or not. It should be computed in a mathematical sense, i.e. `0 *and* anything` will ALWAYS be False. The same applies for `1 *OR* ANYTHING` --> Will ALWAYS yield TRUE, no matter what...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand the dangers of `eval` and just want to return a special value (e.g. 9999) for undefined variables what you can do is customizing the dictionary used by `eval`:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(lambda : 9999)
d['x'] = 21
d['y'] = 2
print(eval('x * y', {}, d))    # ==> 42
print(eval('z', {}, d))        # ==> 9999
```

the only other alternative I can think to is to implement a parser for expressions that uses the `and` logic you are looking for: not a big deal but I'd say it requires a few tens of lines of code.

Comment: I think this is right, but don't you need `eval('z', {}, d)` to make it work?

Comment: @PaulHankin: whoops... sorry, thanks for the heads up

Comment: I'm not sure it's valid to use `d` for globals in eval (which is why I suggested `eval('z', {}, d)` -- the docs say it has to be a dictionary (whereas locals can be "any mapping object"). But I don't know if a defaultdict counts as a dictionary.

Comment: @PaulHankin: you are right about the documentation. It seemed to work but of course this doesn't mean it's valid.